# Access Does Not Contain Query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that needs to select all records from Table "OLRemovedASC" where the [OLRemovedASC].[PartNo] does not equal [qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC].[PartNo] and where [OLRemovedASC].[ProductionDate] does not equal [qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC].[ProductionDate]

I am not good at coding in SQL and have tried a couple different ways in Query design but can't seem to make it work. Below is the query design to show what I have tried.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW OLRemovedASC.*, OLRemovedASC.PostingYM, OLRemovedASC.ProductionYM
FROM OLRemovedASC, [qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC]
WHERE (((OLRemovedASC.PostingYM)>#1/1/2017#) And ((OLRemovedASC.ProductionYM)>#1/1/2017#) And ((OLRemovedASC.PartsNo)<>[qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC].PartsNo) And ((OLRemovedASC.ProductionYM)<>[qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC].ProductionYM));
```

[image]

Comment: If [Data].[PartNo] <> [Above Limit].[PartNo] then there is no record in [Above Limit] to match against [Data].[ProductionDate]. P.S. you should make your description match your graphic, e.g. OlRemovedASC & qry_Claims Above Upper... Also adjust your query screen to show the full tables (width/height) if possible.

Comment: OLRemovedASC has partNo for every month of the productionYM, only some of those month are above limit so I need to have a condition to for both partNo and productionYM. I will update the post.

Comment: @June7 the desired results are that I want any row in OLRemovedASC where partsNo and ProductionYM does not match the same fields in qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC query (Hard to show desired results).

Comment: That sounds like a Find Unmatched query. Access has query wizard for that.

Comment: @June7 That query worked. It was exactly what I needed. Thank You.